# Execute method every time the app launches

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So basically I am using an update checker method (code below) that I want it to run every time the user launches the app

My application hierarchy is like so:

- splash screen
- Main activity with tabs that has 4 fragments (`OneFragment`, `TwoFragment`, `ThreeFragment`...)
- I work in a **fragment**
- I am extending Fragment `extends Fragment`

After the splash screen the OneFragment is executed

**Q:** How to run the `CheckUpdates()` method every time the application is **launched** ? I don't want to run that method every time the fragment is visible or anything like that

> **PS. I tried calling the method in `OnCreate()` and it didn't work, every time I go to another fragment or another activity and return the method is called again**.
>
> So calling it in `OnCreate()` as many of you suggested and marked it as a duplicate didn't solve the isuue

**Here is the method that I will be using**

```
public void checkUpdates(){
   //checking for updates logic
    new AppUpdater(this)
            .setUpdateFrom(UpdateFrom.GOOGLE_PLAY)
            .setDisplay(Display.DIALOG)
            .setTitleOnUpdateAvailable("New update available")
            .setContentOnUpdateAvailable(UPDATE_AVAILABLE)
            .setTitleOnUpdateNotAvailable("No update available")
            .setContentOnUpdateNotAvailable(NO_UPDATE_AVAILABLE)
            .setButtonUpdate("Update")
            .setButtonUpdateClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Goto_ps();
                }
            })
            .setButtonDismiss("Maybe later")
            .setButtonDismissClickListener(null)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .showAppUpdated(true)
            .start();
}
```

Comment: Try put in onResume method

Comment: @brayancamilovillateleon that didn't work